# Lucene Facets - How to handle StoreId

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

We are storing data for multiple stores in the same index.
We want to create facets for several fields , like category (which is hierarchical), price, color, size, price , but we want to calculate these facets per store id.
We will never have a use case - where we want to count across stores.

How do we handle this usecase , shall we add storeid as part of all the values we give to facets , or shall we declare all facets as hierarchical , and have storeid as the first level

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be multiple ways to handle this but based on my experience I'd suggest that when you create your drill down query for your facets (to specify the level in the category hierarchy that you are interest in) and you pass that query a baseQuery, the base query should include your criteria that storeid equals a specific store.

In a sense the storeid needing to be for a specific store is just another query criteria (that you happen to be adding on behind the scenes) for indicating which products the the customer is interested in. This is not much different than if you we also specifying that only products with a specific color are of interest.